# Python copy fails on a class with custom __new__ method

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I have a set of specific defined classes (say colored tubas) and a generic class (say tuba). If an instance of the generic class is created it might return a specific class. I handled this by overriding the `__new__` method of the generic class which checks the input and returns the according class instance.

This works for object creation, e.g. I can say

```
tuba = Tuba('red')
type(tuba)  # will give 'RedTuba'
```

However if I attempt to copy my tuba, Python yields a `TypeError` saying that `__new__` misses 1 required argument. I'm not quite sure I understand how `__new__` should be used correctly in this situation.

How do I need to implement `__new__` in this case to make it work correctly?

```
from copy import copy


class Instrument:
    def __init__(self, kind):
        self.kind = kind


class RedTuba(Instrument):
    # note: RedTuba cannot be derived from Tuba since this is an 
    # abstract example on the actual case I'm having trouble with
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(kind='special-red-tuba')


class Tuba(Instrument):
    def __new__(cls, color):
        if color == 'red':
            return RedTuba.__new__(RedTuba)
        return super().__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, color):
        super().__init__(kind='{}-tuba'.format(color))


r = Tuba('red')
copy(r)  # this works

v = Tuba('violet')
copy(v)  # this does not work
```

The resulting error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "creation.py", line 28, in <module>
    copy(v)
  File "/Users/jul/Envs/latest/lib/python3.7/copy.py", line 106, in copy
    return _reconstruct(x, None, *rv)
  File "/Users/jul/Envs/latest/lib/python3.7/copy.py", line 274, in _reconstruct
    y = func(*args)
  File "/Users/jul/Envs/latest/lib/python3.7/copyreg.py", line 88, in __newobj__
    return cls.__new__(cls, *args)
TypeError: __new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'color'
```

Comment: Make `color` optional in `Tuba` with default `None`.

Comment: Why does it need to be optional?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
from copy import copy
from typing import Optional


class Instrument:
    def __init__(self, kind):
        self.kind = kind


class RedTuba(Instrument):
    # note: RedTuba cannot be derived from Tuba since this is an 
    # abstract example on the actual case I'm having trouble with
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(kind='special-red-tuba')


class Tuba(Instrument):
    def __new__(cls, color: Optional[str] = None):
        color_mapper = {
            'red': RedTuba
        }
        if color in color_mapper:
            tuba_cls = color_mapper[color]
            return tuba_cls.__new__(tuba_cls)
        return super().__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, color):
        super().__init__(kind='{}-tuba'.format(color))
```

I only changed `__new__` in `Tuba`.

The problem is exactly what it says, color was required. Now it's optional.

Subclassing dunder methods is often tricky. Try not to do that if you don't need to. But I see what you're trying to accomplish and it makes sense.

Good luck!